# select from one table, insert into another table oracle sql query

Tags: sql, oracle, select, insert

I am trying to select data from one table 
and insert the data into another table

```
    SELECT ticker FROM tickerdb;
```

Using OracleSql I am trying to 
get the ticker symbol "GOOG" from the tickerdb table, 
and insert the t.ticker into the stockdb table.

select from tickerdb table --> insert into quotedb table

```
    INSERT INTO quotedb
    (t.ticker, q.prevclose, q.opn, q.rnge,
    q.volume, q.marketcap, q.dividend, q.scrapedate)
    VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,SYSDATE)
    tickerdb t inner JOIN quotedb q
    ON t.ticker = q.ticker
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

From the oracle documentation, the below query explains it better

```
INSERT INTO tbl_temp2 (fld_id)
SELECT tbl_temp1.fld_order_id
FROM tbl_temp1 WHERE tbl_temp1.fld_order_id > 100;
```

You can read this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/insert-select.html)

Your query would be as follows

```
//just the concept    
    INSERT INTO quotedb
    (COLUMN_NAMES) //seperated by comma
    SELECT COLUMN_NAMES FROM tickerdb,quotedb WHERE quotedb.ticker = tickerdb.ticker
```

Note: Make sure the columns in insert and select are in right position as per your requirement

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you update the link please ? it's best to quote into you answer if possible to avoid this.

Answer (score 18):

You can use

```
insert into <table_name> select <fieldlist> from <tables>
```

Comment: `INSERT INTO table1 SELECT * FROM table2` works for me in old Oracle10g2 where table1 and table2 have the same table schema

Answer (score 8):

try this query below:

```
Insert into tab1 (tab1.column1,tab1.column2) 
select tab2.column1, 'hard coded  value' 
from tab2 
where tab2.column='value';
```

Comment: Good example which also shows how to create hard coded values in destination table.

Answer (score 4):

You will get useful information from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp).

```
SELECT ticker
INTO quotedb
FROM tickerdb;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error and realized I had left out the Connection Open command.  It worked perfectly after that.