# oracle select few columns from first table and insert (seq.nextval for one column + already selected columns) into second table

Tags: sql, oracle

> PRODUCT1 table:

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCT1(PRD_ID INTEGER , PRD_NAME VARCHAR2(10) );
```

> PRODUCT2 table:

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCT2(PRD_ID INTEGER , PRD_NAME VARCHAR2(10) );
```

> PRODUCT SEQUENCE:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE PRODUCT_SEQ  START WITH 100;
```

**Assume that I have got few records (less than 100) already in PRODUCT1 and PRODUCT2.**

**I am trying below query by using the above tables and sequence:**

```
INSERT INTO PRODUCT2 (PRODUCT_SEQ.NEXTVAL, PRD_NAME) SELECT PRD_NAME FROM PRODUCT1 ;
```

> Error Report: SQL Error: ORA-00947: not enough values

Actually, I have gone through the below post to solve my problem:

[select from one table, insert into another table oracle sql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20261332/select-from-one-table-insert-into-another-table-oracle-sql-query)

But unfortunately, that post has not helped me completely.

Please let me know if you need any more details from my side so that I can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `insert` statement should have the column-names in the table. Then you should select the values from appropriate sequence and table.

```
INSERT INTO PRODUCT2 (PRD_ID, PRD_NAME) 
SELECT PRODUCT_SEQ.NEXTVAL, PRD_NAME FROM PRODUCT1
```

Answer (score 2):

The sequence are  numbers  100 , 102 , 103 ... so you insert those numbers in the column `id`

```
INSERT INTO PRODUCT2 
(PRD_ID, PRD_NAME)
 SELECT PRODUCT_SEQ.NEXTVAL , PRD_NAME FROM PRODUCT1 ;
```

Btw I advise you fix the structure of your column id , it is good practice if you make it `ID number(4)` because you have numbers starting with 100