# Select from multiple tables, insert into another table Oracle SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I have gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20261332/select-from-one-table-insert-into-another-table-oracle-sql-query) link here. I have similar question, but I want data from two different tables. something like this. But it doesn't return the expected results.

```
INSERT INTO tbl_1 (fld_id1,fld_id2)
    SELECT tbl_2.col1
    FROM tbl_2 WHERE someCondi,
    SELECT tbl_3.col1
    FROM tbl_3 WHERE someCondi
```

Eg.

Table1:

```
Col1  Col2  
----------
1      56  
1      57  
1      59
```

Table2:

```
Col1  
----
1
```

Table3

```
col1  
-----
56  
57  
59
```

Comment: The question is a bit unclear, at least to me. Could you add some sample data and the result you'd like to get for this sample?

Comment: Do one `SELECT` where you `JOIN` the tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If (fld_id1,fld_id2) are tbl_2.col1 and tbl_3.col1, so you you have to use `JOIN`

```
INSERT INTO tbl_1 (fld_id1,fld_id2)
SELECT t2.col1, t3.col1
FROM tbl_2 t2 
INNER JOIN tbl_3 t3 ON "JOIN CONDITION" 
WHERE "t2.someCondi"
AND "t3.someCondi"
```

So, if you can't use `JOIN` you can try with Cartesian Product:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_1 (fld_id1,fld_id2)
SELECT t2.col1, t3.col1
FROM tbl_2 t2, tbl_3 t3
WHERE "t2.someCondi"
AND "t3.someCondi"
```

Comment: There is no relationship between tbl_2 and tbl_3 so can't use join.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are looking for a cross join:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_1 (fld_id1,fld_id2)
SELECT t2.col1, t3.col1
FROM table3 t3
  cross join table2 t2
WHERE <some condition>
```

At least with you sample you have shown us, this would return your expected result.